# Azure Mobile Apps authorize filter not honored

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I'm using azure mobile app and i notice that each attribute i put in a controller is not getting honored. only global filters works.

for example

```
[MobileAppController]
[ZboxAuthorize]
public class BoxesController : ApiController
{

    [ZboxAuthorize]
    [Route("api/boxes", Order = 3)]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetBoxesAsync()
    {

        var userid = User.GetCloudentsUserId();
        return Request.CreateResponse("ok");
    }
```

now zboxauthorize attribute is not working. the ctor get called but nothing else

the atuthorize attribute looks like this

```
 public class ZboxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IOverrideFilter
{

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return false;
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("AuthenticationStatus", "NotAuthorized");
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

    }
```

if i put it in my global filter its works perfectly.
what am i missing? thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use [Authorize]? Does it work as expected?

Comment: nop. i open fiddler and do a query without authorization header at all in api call that is wrap with authorize attribute and the request pass.

Comment: Have you turned on app service authentication?

Comment: yes. on the authentication/authorization tab i put on on app service authentication. on the action i put allow request ( no action). on the advanced settings i put token store - off ( to be honest don't know what that mean since lack of documentation) i use custom authentication provider which i build base on this [link](http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/custom-authentication-with-azure-mobile-apps) so i dont need a redirect. i want to return 401 and not to redirect a user.